# Facebook comments on website - moderation view doesn't show on some pages

Tags: facebook, comments

I have a website, and I put in some of the pages the Facebook comment box.
In some of the pages I have (I see) the "moderator view", and in some of them I don't.
Can you help me figure out what is the problem?
Where it works: http://sandfantasy.com/about-me/ - (I can see the moderator view option).
Where it doesn't work: http://sandfantasy.com/video-clips/ (can't see the moderator view option).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `fb:admin` meta tag to enable moderation on a page:

```
meta property="fb:admins" content="{YOUR_FACEBOOK_USER_ID}"
```

Comment: You can see the source of the page, it already exists. I'm using the same code on other pages where it works fine.